# How to Compile Programs Built With Yacc and Lex?

Tags: yacc, lex, compiler-construction

My Yacc source is in pos.yacc and my Lex source is in pos1.lex, as shown.

#### pos1.lex

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"

int yylval;
%}
DIGIT [0-9]+
%%
{DIGIT} {yylval=atoi(yytext);return DIGIT;}
[\n ] {}
. {return *yytext;}
%%
```

#### pos.yacc

```
%token DIGIT
%%
s:e {printf("%d\n",$1);}
e:DIGIT {$$=$1;}
|e e "+" {$$=$1+$2;}
|e e "*" {$$=$1*$2;}
|e e "-" {$$=$1-$2;}
|e e "/" {$$=$1/$2;}
;
%%
main() {
  yyparse();
}
yyerror() {
  printf("Error");
}
```

#### Compilation errors

While compiling I am getting errors like:

```
malathy@malathy:~$ cc lex.yy.c  y.tab.c -ly -ll
pos.y: In function ‘yyerror’:
pos.y:16: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
pos.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
pos.y:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
```

---

- What causes those errors?
- How am I supposed to compile Lex and Yacc source code?

Comment: Please use proper formatting...

Comment: ... and turn off caps lock.

Comment: ...AND DON'T SHOUT. It's considered rude.

Comment: ... and don't tag a question "java" when it's about lex/yacc.

Comment: Don't tell him about Caps Lock! He'll figure out how to turn it on and be able to type much faster...

Comment: What did you do? People put effort into formatting your question correctly...

Answer (score 3):

printf() is defined in stdio.h so just include it above y.tab.h in pos1.lex:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
/* Add  ^^^^^^^^^^^ this line */
#include "y.tab.h"

  int yylval;
%}
DIGIT [0-9]+
%%
{DIGIT} {yylval=atoi(yytext);return DIGIT;}
[\n ] {}
. {return *yytext;}
%%
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the direct answer to your question from [trojanfoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299924/trojanfoe) - you need to include `<stdio.h>` to declare the function `printf()`.  This is true in any source code presented to the C compiler.

However, you should also note that the conventional suffix for Yacc source is `.y` (rather than `.yacc`), and for Lex source is `.l` (rather than `.lex`).  In particular, using those sufffixes means that `make` will know what to do with your source, rather than having to code the compilation rules by hand.

---

Given files `lex.l` and `yacc.y`, `make` compiles them to object code using:

```
$ make lex.o yacc.o
rm -f lex.c 
lex  -t lex.l > lex.c
cc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -c -o lex.o lex.c
yacc  yacc.y 
mv -f y.tab.c yacc.c
cc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -c -o yacc.o yacc.c
rm lex.c yacc.c
$
```

This is in a directory with a makefile that sets `CFLAGS = -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra`.  (This was on MacOS X 10.6.6.)  You will sometimes see other similar rules used; in particular, `lex` generates a file `lex.yy.c` by default (at least on MacOS X), and you'll often see a rule such as:

```
lex lex.l
mv lex.yy.c lex.c
cc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -c -o lex.o lex.c
```

Or even:

```
lex lex.l
cc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -c -o lex.o lex.yy.c
```

The alternatives are legion; use `make` and it gets it right.

Comment: sorry... my yacc file is infix.y and lex file name is in.l...can any one tell me command for these to run and compile...

Answer (score 0):

Include header file stdio.h

for compilation
open terminal locate both files and type

```
lex pos1.l

yacc pos.y

cc lex.yy.c y.tab.h -ll

./a.out
```

You can follow these steps.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to save in file
pos1.l  and pos.y
I hope it will work